# Best practice for simple Laravel model operations

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

Let's say I'm writing a Laravel controller that has a function: make a simple search on a model and do anything with the result. Something like this (without any validation, for simplicity):

```
public function search($name)
{
  $person = Persons:where('name', $name)->first();
  doSomethingWith($person);
  // ...
}
```

Should I move this tiny Eloquent code to the `Person` model in a dedicated function?
Usually I write all the "complex" operations to the Models to have short and readable controllers, but when I have to do little operations like this I always find that moving a single line of code (even if it is directly related to the database) into a separated model function will bring too much overhead to my code.

Comment: Really depends on what the `doSomethingWith($person)` does. If it's just a transformation, you should use a transformer like EloquentResource, if it's changing the `$person` it probably shouldn't be done in the `search()` method. If it's tightly coupled with the `Persons` model, moving it to the model seems reasonable depending on other factors such as the size of the application and reusability of the method. One way or another, this question is not a great fit for StackOverflow

Comment: Hi DevK, thank you for your comment. My question is not related to the `doSomethingWith($person)` but to `$person = Persons:where('name', $name)->first();`

Answer (score 0):

A controller should be free of business logic.
In your case, I don't see business logic in the first line
`$person = Persons:where('name', $name)->first();`
I don't see any reason to write unit tests for this line, so there is no lack of domain knowledge to the controller and you can leave it in the controller

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could follow this MVC pattern with more patterns. You could learn more about this from here: [DevSkill](https://youtu.be/4WfqXx2gWxo). Make sure you watch the video with subtitle, cause it's a Bangladeshi Language video. That's why subtitle will help you to understand the standard MVC pattern software development. Actually, I am also following this convention to develop software with Laravel